# Change emacs theme color for a specific LaTeX command

Tags: emacs, themes, latex, elisp

I am trying to customize the `tsdh-dark` emacs theme, which I find particularly relaxing.

I am able to customize colors for functions, comments, etc.

However, typing LaTeX documents, particular kind of elements, such as custom or not built-in commands, have a color too close to default text.

See for example the `\hypersetup` command versus his content:

[image: piece of latex code]

or `shorttitle`,  `\hh`, `tr` versus normal text:

[image: latex highligthed text]

How can I change this color?

Comment: Try placing your cursor on the color you want to change and type `M-x customize-face`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It worked, and it was the `font-latex-sedate-face` parameter. However, it does not apply if the command is inside the `\title` environment. It is like there is a sort of priority. For example,  `\footnote`  inside `\title` has another color, but `\hh` inside `\title` does not.

Comment: The AUCTeX library is overly complicated (in my opinion), and I use a custom modified version of the built-in `tex-mode.el`.  I would suggest writing up a separate question on the regexp or font-lock rule used by the library to highlight certain aspects that you wish to change.  Forum participants like *giordano* are intimately familiar with AUCTeX and could suggest a solution if there are sufficient details regarding what you desire changing.  For those of us not intimately familiar with it, changing the regexp would be a little time-consuming to figure out -- doable, but not second-nature.

Comment: Here is a link to another forum where you may get quicker answers for AUCTeX related questions:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs

Comment: Thank you very much to all. I will considerate this if I really feel that the workflow is not so straight. Currently I am happy with my new `font-latex-sedate-face` color which works for not-nested commands.